# Given a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$, if $m$ is relatively prime to $|H|$ and $x^m\in\ker f$, then $x\in \ker f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $f:G\to H$ be a homomorphism, and let  $m$ be an integer such that $m$ and $|H|$ are relatively prime. For any $x \in G$, if $x^m \in \ker f$, then $x \in \ker f$.

My proof step:  if $x^m \in \ker f$, $e=f (x^m)=( f(x))^m$, $f(x)\in H$, $\operatorname{ord} f (x)\leq m$

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: [Please look at how I've edited your post](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/5a202edc-822f-4d8b-bd7d-6940329edcac/view-source), and try to emulate it in the future. [You can go here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: 1. What is $H$, what is $G$, what is $f$, ... 2. Choose $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $um + v |H|=1$ and conclude.

Comment: if f: G to H is a homomorphism

Comment: What is $H$? Is it supposed to be $G$?, or $ker f$?

Comment: If f: G→H is a homomorphism

Comment: What sort of homomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so $e = f(x^m) = f(x)^m$ by definition.

This tells you that $f(x)$ has order dividing $m$ in $H$. But Lagrange's theorem tells us that the order of $f(x)$ divides $|H|$. Since they are coprime this order must be $1$, hence $f(x) = e$, telling us that $x$ is in the kernel.